# Is there a reason why Chrome does not allow Image Maps to link to external pages?

Tags: google-chrome, imagemap

I am creating a basic interactive wireframe sequence. It uses a combination of target + image map. The code is below:

```
  <div id="container" >

    <main>

        <section id="wireframe">
            <div   id="loader">
            <img src="images/wires/iphone-page-01.png" alt="step-01" usemap="#mobile-01"/>
            <map id="mobile-01" name="mobile-01"  href="pages/mobile-02.html"  >
            <area shape="rect" coords="23,418,440,473" alt="PRODUCTS" title="PRODUCTS" href="pages/mobile-04.html" target="_self"  />
            </map>
            </div>
            <div id="placeholder"></div>
        </section>

    </main>
    <footer></footer>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('map').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#loader").load($(this).attr('href'));
  });

});
```

This works perfectly fine in Safari and Firefox but Chrome will not load the page in the loader even if the image map area is a link. If I right click > open link in new window, it loads the page fine, however it prevents me from loading the page in itself.

Is there some weird useless security issue within Chrome preventing this?